# Xerces-c can't parse inverted question mark

Tags: c++, xml, character-encoding, xerces-c

We have xml messages that come from an external system via soap envelopes. If there is an encoding header then we use it otherwise we provide one with UTF-8.

Recently we've been getting messages with interesting characters such as inverted question mark : ¿, accented letters, etc

Our system that processes these messages is failing to parse this. I noticed the format for these XMLs were iso-8859-1 - so I tried changing it to UTF-8 to see if the parser would play ball, but still no luck.

Knowing UTF-8 supports wider range, I checked the character set table for iso-8859-1 here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1. It seems inverted question marks, accented letters are supported.

I'm hitting a wall with this and would really appreciate some help! Thanks!

C++/stl code using xerces-c 2.7.0 compiling with gnu compiler 3.4 on a x86 linux machine.

Comment: Normally, an XML writer should encode such characters using entity encoding...

Comment: As leemes says, the problem isn't the character set you are using, but the fact that XML expects a lot of special characters to be properly encoded as &something; rather than as literals in the code. So whoever is sending you this data is basically sending you invalid XML.

Comment: @OriginalCliche: Did you actually re-encode the message contents into UTF-8, or did you just change the xml header from "iso-8859-1" to "utf-8"? It's not only that "...UTF-8 supports wider range", the problem is that the codes are different. The inverted question mark might show up as two bytes (0xc2 0xbf) whereas in iso-8859-1 it is one byte (0xbf)

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have pointed out, "special" characters are not necessarily supported by the XML reader. This is not a unique problem to `xerces-c`, but also happens in several versions of JavaScript XML parsers. I ended up solving this for my problem (names of rivers in South America for example, containing various accented letters that are encoded as multiple characters in UTF-8) by using the &#nnn; nomenclature, based on the tables here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-lat1.ent

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input on this. I think it makes a lot of sense that the characters should be encoded as oppose to literals. I will discuss with the provider of these XML content and see if they can send us properly encoded XML message. IF NOT - do any of you know of any library that can help with converting literals to proper encoded XML? It'd add overheads to our server, but at the very least it would provide some immediate solution while discussions continues with the third party vendors. Thanks Again everyone!

Comment: If you want more support for "the supplier of the XML needs to fix things", try loading the XML in your browser [Try IE, FireFox and/or Chrome]. If it turns out "funny", then you know it's thoroughly broken. It's quite possible that the supplier of the XML only ever used ONE variant of XML parser, that happens to work. You may also want to try with JavaScript, using this ` var parser=new DOMParser(); xmlContent = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");` where `xmlString` is your string of XML content.